# Matching text between hyphens with regex

Tags: regex

Currently I have this string:

```
"RED-CURRENT_FORD-something.something"
```

I need to capture the word between the hyphens. In this case the word `CURRENT_FORD`.

I have the following written:

```
\CURRENT_.*\B-\
```

Which returns `CURRENT_FORD-` which is wrong on two levels.

1. It implies that everything between hyphens starts with `CURRENT`.
2. It includes the hyphen at the end.

Is there a way to capture the words in between the hyphens without explicitly stating the first word?

Comment: a `regex` based question **should be** tagged with the `language` u r using...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the delimiters to help bound your pattern then *capture* what you want with parentheses.

```
/-([^-]+)-/
```

You can then trim the hyphens off.

Comment: if it's js regex, can't you use look ahead/behind?

Comment: I tend to avoid *looks*. Seems unnecessary when using a capture.

Answer (score 6):

You can use these regex

```
(?<=-).*?(?=-)//if lookaround is supported
```

**OR**

```
-(.*?)-//captured in group1
```

---

`.*?` matches any character i.e. `.` 0 to many times i.e. `*` lazily i.e `?`

`(?<=-)` is a zero width look behind assertion that would match for the character `-` before the desired match i.e `.*?` and `(?=-)` is a zero width look ahead assertion that matches for `-` character after matching `.*?`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=-)\w+(?=-)
```

any sequence or "word"-characters, between hyphens which do themselves not take part in the capture (look-behind and look-ahead conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the word boundary option:

```
/^.*-\b(\w+)\b-.*$/
```

This is actually 3 (well, 2) parts:

```
^.*-\b
```

says all characters from the beginning of the token until a dash followed by a word boundary (an invisible boundary between 'word characters' and non 'word characters')

```
(\w+)
```

captures the bit between the dashes and puts it into a matched pattern variable (that's what the brackets are for)

The last part is just a repeat of the first part to match any other characters after the dash.