# Regex - finding a string between the last two “-“

Tags: regex

I would like to extract the string between the last two “-“ (T-shirt also has “-“ and it ruins my results.

For example:

```
T-shirt Layla gaga-papa-lk
```

So I want to return “papa”. I tried to use `(?<=-)[^-)]+(?=-)` but it doesn’t work on this example because of the t-shirt.

On this example it does work:

```
Gh world papa -mama-p
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13292007/3832970) (though the pattern is a bit redundant) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354786/3832970) might be enough for you. And here is an [R solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57554717/3832970) (basically, the same as the first linked solution, but with replacing logic).

Answer (score 2):

You might update the pattern to:

```
(?<=-)[^-\n]+(?=-[^-\n]*$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=-)` Assert a `-` to the left
- `[^-\n]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `-` or a newline
- `(?=-[^-\n]*$)` Assert a `-` to the right, followed by any char except `-` or a newline until the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6IklaP/1)

Or using a capture group instead of lookarounds:

```
-([^-\n]+)-[^-\n]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6yo60/1)

The `\n` in the negated character class is to not match crossing newlines.

There is no `)` in the example data, but if you also don't want to match that you can add it to the negated character class `[^-\n)]+`

Answer (score 0):

You could match the following regular expression:

```
(?=[^\n-]*\-[^\n-]*$)[^\n-]*
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/uHHZlu/1)

`(?=[^\n-]*\-[^\n-]*$)` is a *positive lookahead* which becomes satisfied when the regex engine has moved its internal string pointer from the beginning of the string to just past the penultimate hyphen. If the string were `"a-b-c-d-e"` the lookahead would become satisfied when the pointer were between the third hyphen and the letter `"d"`. The desired string therefore consists of the characters between that location and the next (last) hyphen.

The regex can be broken down as follows.

```
(?=        # begin positive lookahead
  [^\n-]*  # match zero or more characters other than a newline or hyphen
  \-       # match a hyphen
  [^\n-]*  # match zero or more characters other than a newline or hyphen
  $        # match end of string
)          # end positive lookahead
[^\n-]*    # match zero or more characters other than a newline or hyphen
```

Notice the repetition in this expression, with `[^\n-]*` appearing three times. If the regex engine supports [subroutines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) (or *sub-expressions*) the expression can be simplified as follows (I've used the PCRE engine syntax for illustration):

```
(?=([^\n-]*)\-(?1)$)(?1)
```

[Numbered groups subroutine demo](https://regex101.com/r/sutcNd/1)

or

```
(?=(?P<non_hyphens>[^\n-]*)\-(?P>non_hyphens)$)(?P>non_hyphens)
```

[Named groups subroutine demo](https://regex101.com/r/NI937C/1)

Subroutines, especially with named groups, make regular expressions more compact, easier to follow and reduce careless coding errors.